# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add firebase cloud storage to my app. Below is the app build.gradle. But it says: 
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1.
Why? There is no firebase-core in the dependencies at all.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.louise.udacity.mydict"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.31.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: if you are using kotlin than:

Replace:
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

with:
 kapt 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

and your top level gradle file add
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

Answer (score 116, accepted):

From the docs:-

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

Add:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

and in top level gradle file use the latest version of google play services:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services

**Note:**

You need to add the `google()` repo in the top level gradle file, as specified in the firebase docs and also it should be before `jcenter()`:

```
 buildscript {
  repositories {
          google()
          jcenter()
      }



dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
   }
}

allprojects {
     repositories {
              google()
             jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: I added firebase-core, but same error occurs. btw, I used firebase assistant in android studio to add firebase cloud.

Comment: it also says: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html. But i double checked all build.gradle files. I'm using implementation instead of comple for all dependencies.

Comment: clean and rebuild the project, what android version plugin are u using?

Comment: yes, I tried "clean" and "rebuild", same result. What do you mean by "android version plugin"? So if I delete firebase-storage and firebase-auth dependencies, the error disappeared. Once adding the 2 dependencies back, it looks like something is forcing firebase-core to 16.0.1, then failed.

Comment: this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'` and this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Comment: oh, my "com.google.gms:google-services" was 3.XX, i just upgraded to 4.0.1, the problem solved. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I had same issue, for my case I just changed the version from 16.0.0 to "11.0.4" because that was available version for play-services in my system.
So people facing similar issue don't just change versions randomly as its not gonna work.

Comment: u need to upgrade google-service plugin to version 4.0.2 to be able to use 16.0.1 @sanky No one is upgrading randomly everything is explained. If you want to use 16.0.1 then you need to update google-service plugin

Comment: Adding google() in repositories of allprojects manually worked for me...

Comment: @Shachi yup as I said in the Note you need to add the `google() ` to be able to use firebase services.

Comment: Yup.. +1 for that... simple and concise @PeterHaddad

Comment: Just adding this: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2' solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Since [May 23, 2018 update](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), when you're using a firebase dependency, you must include the `firebase-core` dependency, too.

If adding it, you still having the error, try to update the gradle plugin in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` to 4.5 version:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5-all.zip
```

and resync the project.

Comment: I added firebase-core, but same error occurs. btw, I used firebase assistant in android studio to add firebase cloud.

Comment: +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0 -> 16.0.1 FAILED
I tried to run gradle dependencies, and it displayed the entry above. Looks like it intentionally convert 16.0.0 (which i declared in build.gradle) to 16.0.1. Do you know why it happens and how to modify the settings?

Comment: Same here. It is working just fine with 16.0.0, but fails when I upgrade to 16.0.1. I am using all the latest Android Gradle and GMS configurations, plus gradle 4.7. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, gradle-4.5 was the thing I was in need. Using 4.4, I was getting the error.

Comment: This version is old. Please don't run into compatibility issues. Please upgrade everything to the latest.

Answer (score 6):

Add maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } to your root level build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As @Peter Haddad mentioned above,

To fix this issue I followed Google firebase integration guidelines and did the following changes in my app/build.gradle and project/build.gradle

Follow below mentioned link if you have any doubts

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

**changes in app/build.gradle**

```js
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.2'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0"
```

**Changes in Project/build.gradle**

```js
repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'// // google-services plugin it should be latest if you are using firebase version 16.0 +
       
    }
    allprojects {
    repositories {
         google()// add it to top instead of bottom or somewhere in middle
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
       
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I get the same issue and i solved it by replacing :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
```

and everything solved and worked well.

Comment: You will encounter compatibility issues in near future then. Please upgrade everything to the latest.

Answer (score 4):

What actually was missing for me and what made it work then was downloading'Google Play services' and 'Google Repository'

Go to: Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> check/install Google Play services + repository

[image: SDK Tools Settings SS]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue by following these steps-

1.) This error occurs when you didn't connect your project to firebase. 
Do that from **Tools->Firebase** if you are using Android studio version 2.2 or above.

2.) Make sure you have replaced the `compile` with `implementation` in `dependencies in app/build.gradle`

3.) Include your firebase dependency from the firebase docs. Everything should work fine now

Answer (score 2):

This is rare, but there is a chance your project's gradle offline mode is enable, disable offline mode with the following steps;

- In android studio, locate the file tab of the header and click
- In the drop own menu, select settings
- In the dialog produced, select "Build, Execution, Deploy" and then select "Gradle"
- Finally uncheck the "offline work" check box and apply changes

If this doesn't work leave a comment describing your Logcat response and i'll try to help more.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was resolved by changing the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 26 to 27

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firebase in a library module, you need to apply the google play services gradle plugin to it in addition to the app(s) module(s), but also, you need to beware of version 4.2.0 (and 4.1.0) which are broken, and use version 4.0.2 instead.

Here's the issue: https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

if you are using

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

in app-level gradle, and

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

in project-level gradle
and you have added the 
google-services.json file to your project.

you need to add just below code

```
maven {
   url "https://maven.google.com"
}
```

at below of jcenter() in repositories blocks in project-level gradle file
here are my gradle files:

project-level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and app-level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.moslem.amazonlikeapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code and update all firebase versions that will work

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you receive an error stating the library cannot be found, check the Google maven repo for your library and version.  I had a version suddenly disappear and make my builds fail.

https://maven.google.com/web/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools ->

and make sure you install Google Play Services