# failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

i have android project 
and i want to add push notifications to that app using google firebase 
first i downloaded the xml file and past it on app root then
i added this lines as they said on this link

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
  }
}
    dependencies {
  // Add this line
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}
...
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and i click sync now 
always gat this error

```
failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0
```

thank for help
this is the full gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.softya.demo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is the gradle file code

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you please show complete `build.gradle`? Maybe your forgot to put `jcenter()` and `google()` in your build script repositories.

Comment: updated the question thank

Comment: Is it all your top-level `build.gradle`? Not the app level, but the project / top level `build.gradle`

Comment: yes and i added the ather gradle file

Comment: Pls accept the answer if it works on your project. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586177/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core16-0-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice you need to updates a lot of your scripts.

For example, let's start with your top-level `build.gradle`. You should no longer use android gradle plugin 2.+, instead you should use version 3.1.x

And to do that, you should put `google()` in your repositories.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      //Add this line
      google()
   }
   dependencies {
      //Please update it to 3.1.x
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
      //Update to the latest version as well
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
      // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}
```

Some tips:

Try to update your app-level `build.gradle`, from `compile` to `implementation` since they will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the google() Google's Maven repository for all projects

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with this script in the build.gradle [Proyect]

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```