# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, build

In my android app's build file, I have given a wrong version of the library `"com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0"` for now the latest version is `"com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"`.

Later, I corrected the build file to use the correct version `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'`. Now while building the app, I am still getting the error.

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0
```

I even tried to delete the dependency `"com.google.firebase:firebase-core****"` but still I am getting the error. Please help me to resolve.

[image]

Comment: Why using `api`? Try with `implementation` then make sure you have `google()` in your root build.gradle. However, updating the gradle will solve the issue most of the time. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50789520/4409113

Answer (score 0):

Use same dependency for ads as used for the Core in your case (16.0.4).
Or follow this link for Further Instruction.

[https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup][1]

Also use implementation instead of api.