# Failed to resolve:com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0

Tags: java, android, firebase

[image]

> Failed to resolve:com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0

There occurs an error in: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'  which is creating difficulty in running the project.

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50586236/3172725)

Answer (score 0):

just rename google-services(1).json to google-services.json..may be it will work.

Answer (score 0):

this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586177/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core16-0-1/50586236#50586236) may help you. Check this out.

open your build:gradle(project file) and check if there is google play service classpath and google() repo is added or not.

Comment: If you are talking about "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' ",then it's already added at the bottom of the app/build(gradle) and in project/build.gradle also.

Comment: did you add this google maven repo?

`allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}`

in your project/build.gradle