# Gradle Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.4

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to generate token in order to send the push notification for that i have added the following dependency in the gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

but it is showing the following error message :

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.4

How to resolve that error?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586177/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core16-0-1

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'` to your build.gradle.

And in your top level gradle file : `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'`

Comment: now it is showing the following error                                                           Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.4.